# Use logical equivalences to prove that ( ∧ ) → q is a tautology

Tags: logic

Use logical equivalences to prove that ( ∧ ) → q is a tautology

I have no idea how to start this, is this not a given?

Answer (score 2):

$$ (p \land q) \rightarrow q $$
Definition of Material Conditional:
$$ \neg(p \land q) \lor q $$
De Morgan's Law:
$$ \neg p \lor \neg q \lor q $$
By the Law of Negation, since either $ q $ or $ \neg q$ must be true, the statement is always true; it is a tautology.